# SQL Server error in IIS asp.net web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis

Good day everyone!
I've been having a problem, and I figure it out that I'm not the only one with this 'kind' of SQL Exception. But, I done everything that I found and with the same result. So, please, let me introduce my problem.

I've been working in asp.net web application. Developed in Visual Studio 2015 (community version). In my project I have some SQL Connection to my local database (in the same computer that my project). Everything is going well when I click "Debug" (with my favorite browser). I can make querys (select, inset, update, etc). Now I want to make it public in my intranet (my cowerkers want to wwork with this app as well). So, I moved my project folder to

> C:\inetpub\wwwroot

And yes, the IIS web site is configured (correctly, I think, well I have another intranet apps working fine!)

The Default page in my web page is a Login.aspx and when I try to access with the correct keys (username and password), SQL shows me an error.

> Invalid login attempt. Database
>   issue.System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Error de inicio
>   de sesión del usuario 'IIS APPPOOL\SADI'. en
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean
>   applyTransientFaultHandling) en
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions) en
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
>   DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) en
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) en
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) en
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) en
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) en
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection) en
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) en
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) en
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() en
>   SADMIN.Login.btnLog_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) en
>   C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\Login.aspx.cs:line 43
>   ClientConnectionId:6cc4ef30-4720-4c45-ba87-d85f39804685 Error
>   Number:18456,State:1,Class:14 Enviar

And if your're wondering... This is my line 43:

```
conn.Open();
```

And this my BackCode in the Login.aspx

```
  try
                 {

                     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security
 Info=False;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Data
 Source=PCUsername\SQLInstance");
                     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                     SqlDataReader reader;

                     cmd.CommandText = "spcLoginValidate";
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                     cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtusername.Text;
                     cmd.Parameters.Add("@passw", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtpassword.Text;

                     cmd.Connection = conn;
                     conn.Open();

                     reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                     while (reader.Read())
                     {
                         idRole = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0].ToString());
                         Session["User"] = reader[1].ToString();
                         Session["ID"] = idRole;

                     }



                     reader.Close();
                     conn.Close();

                     lblError.Visible = true;
                 }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                 {
                     lblError.Text = "Invalid login attempt. Database issue." + ex;
                     lblError.Visible = true;

                 }
```

In the Catch section I have the labelError whith the SQL Exception, and in that label is where my web page shows me the error that I gave you before.

My SQL Server services are running, so I don´t know what to do!
Any help from you guys it would be awesome! 
I've been trying to resolve this issue for 3 days, and still have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after 4 days searching for information about this issue.
And still don't know the reason.

I found what I need, after all, this resolved my problem.
I just ran this sentence in SQL Server's query (inside my database)

```
 exec sp_grantlogin 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'  
 use yourDB exec
 sp_grantdbaccess 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'
```

Special thanks to Moho and Steve B, your answers were fundamental to found the resolution.

Answer (score 4):

You need to grant your IIS AppPool\SADI account access to the DB *or* disable integrated security and add a password for the `sa` user account.

Creating SQL Server Logins and DB Users:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337545(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: added a link to a technet article

Comment: well. Sql server login and db user done it... but how cain I grant the accoount access (IIS AppPool\SADI). Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The error is self explaining. Your application pool account does not have sufficient rights on the SQL database.

You  may:

1. change the identity of your application to a domain account, and grant privileges to this account on the DB
2. change SQL authentication to user/password and create a sql login (not recommended though)

Also please check if user impersonation is disabled in the web.config file (this may lead to such issue if not)

Comment: I did the number 2. But still the same issue. And

Comment: as [@Moho stated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36361258/588868), your connexion string is still setup to use integrated security. User id and password won't be used.